# MUI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for ""

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, react-hook-form

I'm having problems with AutoComplete from MUI using react-hook-form I followed the instruction from [mui here](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#CountrySelect.js) but it's not working now, i have tried to  remove `value={value}` from autoComplete and it seemed to work but I only get 0.

I have made a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-5j3tyg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I guess the problem is here ``${option.label} (${option.code})``. Since you set the value as empty string, so `"".label` and `"".code` would return `undefined`. Also Here is the signature of  `AutoComplete` `onChange` `function(event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: T | Array<T>, reason: string, details?: string) => void`. You need to get the value from second argument. working example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-forked-hx22xu?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: yes I see what you mean, I was thinking wrongly that `getOptionLabel` also was a part of what it returned, but I see now that it returns an obj not a string and I noticted that you also changed `onChange` and gave it 2 parameters but you only use 1 why is that?